# "Lock" dictionary in signature field is the reason of broken signature after signing

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

In PDFBox 2.x I put `/Lock` dictionary to signature field:

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDictionary;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSName;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDAcroForm;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDSignatureField;

public class SigningUtils {
    public static final COSName COS_NAME_LOCK = COSName.getPDFName("Lock");
    public static final COSName COS_NAME_ACTION = COSName.getPDFName("Action");
    public static final COSName COS_NAME_ALL = COSName.getPDFName("All");
    public static final COSName COS_NAME_SIG_FIELD_LOCK = COSName.getPDFName("SigFieldLock");

    public static void setLock(PDSignatureField pdSignatureField, PDAcroForm acroForm) {
        COSDictionary lockDict = new COSDictionary();
        lockDict.setItem(COS_NAME_ACTION, COS_NAME_ALL);
        lockDict.setItem(COSName.TYPE, COS_NAME_SIG_FIELD_LOCK);
        pdSignatureField.getCOSObject().setItem(COS_NAME_LOCK, lockDict);
    }
}
```

Then I sign the signature field:

```
PDSignature signature = findExistingSignature(document, signatureFieldName); //This is some method to find signature field and create PDSignature dictionary

signature.setFilter(PDSignature.FILTER_ADOBE_PPKLITE);
signature.setSubFilter(PDSignature.SUBFILTER_ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);

signature.setName("blablabla");
signature.setLocation("blablabla");
signature.setReason("blablabla");
signature.setSignDate(Calendar.getInstance());
document.addSignature(signature, this);
```

Everything looks allright except that when I open signed document in Adobe Acrobat it complains the content of the document was changed. If I don't add the `/Lock` dictionary the everything is fine.

Anyone has any idea what is wrong?

Comment: How did you save your file?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I call `save` after adding `/Lock` dictionary, then load to a new `PDDocument`, and then call `saveIncremental` after signing.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I have to add signature field to the document in one separate phase, and in another step I place a signature, so I have to call `save` in the first phase. If I open the document created in the first phase in Adobe Reader, and then place signature in that program, then everything is allright.

Comment: Then reopen the saved document.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I do it already :-) Finally I found the solution - I have to add: `lockDict.setInt(COSName.getPDFName("P"), 1);` while adding `/Lock` dictionary.

Comment: Glad to hear that... Consider answering the question yourself. /P is not mentioned in the PDF 32000 specification. Maybe in one of the errata? It is mentioned in the 2.0 specification.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I also didn't find such a key in pdf spec. The solution is based on the observation of the structure of pdf file produced by Foxit Reader. I'll try to do further reading, maybe there's a better solution.

Comment: It is weird that adding the **P** value to the lock dictionary should make a difference because using that value *permissions can be denied but not added*. If *"Adobe Acrobat complains the content of the document was changed"* without that value, it should continue complaining with that value because **P** could not permit you to do such changes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that PDFBox signing does not take the **Lock** dictionary into account.

According to ISO 32000-1 (and also similarly ISO 32000-2):

> #### 12.8.2.4 FieldMDP
>
> The **FieldMDP** transform method shall be used to detect changes to the values of a list of form fields. The entries in its transform parameters dictionary are listed in Table 256.
>
> [...]
>
> - The author can also specify that after a specific recipient has signed the document, any modifications to specific form fields shall invalidate that recipient’s signature. There shall be a separate signature field for each designated recipient, each having an associated signature field lock dictionary (see Table 233) specifying the form fields that shall be locked for that user.
> - When the recipient signs the field, the signature, signature reference, and transform parameters dictionaries shall be created. The **Action** and **Fields** entries in the transform parameters dictionary shall be copied from the corresponding fields in the signature field lock dictionary.

Thus, the expected handling of a signature **Lock** dictionary includes the addition of matching **FieldMDP** transform data to the signature field value. PDFBox signing does not do so by default.

You can manually do it like this during signing:

```
PDSignatureField signatureField = FIND_YOUR_SIGNATURE_FIELD_TO_SIGN;
PDSignature signature = new PDSignature();
signatureField.setValue(signature);

COSBase lock = signatureField.getCOSObject().getDictionaryObject(COSName.getPDFName("Lock"));
if (lock instanceof COSDictionary)
{
    COSDictionary lockDict = (COSDictionary) lock;
    COSDictionary transformParams = new COSDictionary(lockDict);
    transformParams.setItem(COSName.TYPE, COSName.getPDFName("TransformParams"));
    transformParams.setItem(COSName.V, COSName.getPDFName("1.2"));
    transformParams.setDirect(true);
    COSDictionary sigRef = new COSDictionary();
    sigRef.setItem(COSName.TYPE, COSName.getPDFName("SigRef"));
    sigRef.setItem(COSName.getPDFName("TransformParams"), transformParams);
    sigRef.setItem(COSName.getPDFName("TransformMethod"), COSName.getPDFName("FieldMDP"));
    sigRef.setItem(COSName.getPDFName("Data"), document.getDocumentCatalog());
    sigRef.setDirect(true);
    COSArray referenceArray = new COSArray();
    referenceArray.add(sigRef);
    signature.getCOSObject().setItem(COSName.getPDFName("Reference"), referenceArray);
}

signature.setFilter(PDSignature.FILTER_ADOBE_PPKLITE);
signature.setSubFilter(PDSignature.SUBFILTER_ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
signature.setName("blablabla");
signature.setLocation("blablabla");
signature.setReason("blablabla");
signature.setSignDate(Calendar.getInstance());
document.addSignature(signature [, ...]);
```

*([CreateSignature](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/sign/CreateSignature.java#L328) helper method `signExistingFieldWithLock`)*

---

Concerning the **P** entry in the signature **Lock** dictionary discussed in the comments: This entry has been introduced in the Adobe supplement to ISO 32000, extension level 3.

Comment: An improved version that additionally makes the fields protected by the signature read-only and locked can be found [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59049571/1729265).