# PDF signing by PDFBox with Lock

Tags: pdf, pdfbox, signing

I want to sign a pdf by using Lock. I am using PDFBox 2.0.9

The flow I want to achieve is:

- I will create a document with a form field
- I want to sign the document but exclude that form field
- After signing this document I want to change the value of that field
- I will sign again with no exclusion

So if someone edit this form field again, Adobe Reader should say that this document has changed.

["Lock" dictionary in signature field is the reason of broken signature after signing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49894319/lock-dictionary-in-signature-field-is-the-reason-of-broken-signature-after-sig/49964903)

I got the example code from here and I wrote this one:

```
PDSignatureField signatureField = getSignatureField(pdDocument, pdSignature);
if (signatureField != null) {
    COSDictionary lockDict = new COSDictionary();
    lockDict.setItem(COSName.TYPE, COS_NAME_SIG_FIELD_LOCK);
    lockDict.setItem(COS_NAME_ACTION, COS_NAME_EXCLUDE);

    COSArray lockFields = new COSArray();
    lockFields.add(new COSString("textbox1"));

    lockDict.setItem(COS_NAME_FIELDS, lockFields);

    signatureField.getCOSObject().setItem(COS_NAME_LOCK, lockDict);

    COSDictionary transformParams = new COSDictionary(lockDict);
    transformParams.setItem(COSName.TYPE, COSName.getPDFName("TransformParams"));
    transformParams.setItem(COSName.V, COSName.getPDFName("1.2"));
    transformParams.setDirect(true);
    COSDictionary sigRef = new COSDictionary();
    sigRef.setItem(COSName.TYPE, COSName.getPDFName("SigRef"));
    sigRef.setItem(COSName.getPDFName("TransformParams"), transformParams);
    sigRef.setItem(COSName.getPDFName("TransformMethod"), COSName.getPDFName("FieldMDP"));
    //sigRef.setItem(COSName.getPDFName("Data"), pdDocument.getDocumentCatalog());
    sigRef.setDirect(true);
    COSArray referenceArray = new COSArray();
    referenceArray.add(sigRef);
    pdSignature.getCOSObject().setItem(COSName.getPDFName("Reference"), referenceArray);

}
```

I can sign, change the field value and sign again and signatures are okay. The problem is when I change the value of the field after the second signature, signatures are still valid. I am expecting that after last change, the second signature must be invalid.

Comment: *"The problem is I can sign once and everything is okay but after the second signing, the first signature becomes invalid with this error: SigDict/Contents illegal data"* - do you save using incremental updates?

Comment: Yes, should not I?

Comment: Yes, you should. But it wasn't clear that you do.

Comment: Do you have any idea what would be the cause? And also for that case I commented out the line which set Data. Is it used to handle all form elements?

Comment: *"Do you have any idea what would be the cause?"* - not yet. I'm going to do some tests next week. Just to be sure, you use a different field for the second signature, don't you?

Comment: Could you share some pdf in multiple states? Like one copy for each of your 4 steps?

Comment: First of all, I am sorry that, I miscoded one line on the third stage that uses save instead of saveIncremental. Now signature is okay but when I change the fields value after the second signature, it still accepts as form fills but I expect that it should say document has been changed. Then I commented out the lines I used above, the behavior is same so still I am creating this dictionary wrong or I understand something wrong. Do you want me to share PDFs which are signed in both ways?

Comment: Please first update your question (use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54596361/edit) link underneath the question text) to reflect your current code and problem state.

Comment: I solved the problem, thank you for your help, should I edit the question or should I create a question which describes my bad.

Comment: I mean I solved because I have found my bad in the code above, I was adding the exclusion for all not just for the first one.

Comment: Please create an answer instead. And if the answer by mkl helped, upvote it.

Comment: I did but because of my reputation nothing changed, thanks all of you a lot.

Comment: Great that you could resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my code, because this code adds excluding every time. When I coded like below (my first signatures name is Signature 1), everything became normal as expected.

```
    public static final COSName COS_NAME_LOCK = COSName.getPDFName("Lock");
    public static final COSName COS_NAME_ACTION = COSName.getPDFName("Action");
    public static final COSName COS_NAME_ALL = COSName.getPDFName("All");
    public static final COSName COS_NAME_INCLUDE = COSName.getPDFName("Include");
    public static final COSName COS_NAME_EXCLUDE = COSName.getPDFName("Exclude");
    public static final COSName COS_NAME_FIELDS = COSName.getPDFName("Fields");
    public static final COSName COS_NAME_SIG_FIELD_LOCK = COSName.getPDFName("SigFieldLock");


        PDSignatureField signatureField = getSignatureField(pdDocument, pdSignature);
        if (signatureField != null) {
            COSDictionary lockDict = new COSDictionary();
            lockDict.setItem(COSName.TYPE, COS_NAME_SIG_FIELD_LOCK);
            lockDict.setItem(COS_NAME_ACTION, COS_NAME_EXCLUDE);

            COSArray lockFields = new COSArray();
            if (pdSignature.getName().equals("Signature1")) {
                lockFields.add(new COSString("textbox1"));
            }

            lockDict.setItem(COS_NAME_FIELDS, lockFields);

            signatureField.getCOSObject().setItem(COS_NAME_LOCK, lockDict);

            COSDictionary transformParams = new COSDictionary(lockDict);
            transformParams.setItem(COSName.TYPE, COSName.getPDFName("TransformParams"));
            transformParams.setItem(COSName.V, COSName.getPDFName("1.2"));
            transformParams.setDirect(true);
            COSDictionary sigRef = new COSDictionary();
            sigRef.setItem(COSName.TYPE, COSName.getPDFName("SigRef"));
            sigRef.setItem(COSName.getPDFName("TransformParams"), transformParams);
            sigRef.setItem(COSName.getPDFName("TransformMethod"), COSName.getPDFName("FieldMDP"));
            sigRef.setDirect(true);
            COSArray referenceArray = new COSArray();
            referenceArray.add(sigRef);
            pdSignature.getCOSObject().setItem(COSName.getPDFName("Reference"), referenceArray);

        }
```