# Add lock Dictionary on Certify Signature PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

Use PDFBox 2.0.25 tryng to

1. certify with ***P*** set 2
2. lock the certify signature

sample code is from example `CreateVisibleSignature.java` from `signPDF()` function

sample code

```
 public boolean signPDF(File inputFile, File signedFile,  Rectangle2D humanRect, String tsaUrl, int page, String SignatureField, boolean isWithQR, String name, UserSignature userSignature) throws IOException, CertificateEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, OperatorCreationException, CMSException {
    if (inputFile == null || !inputFile.exists()) {
        throw new IOException("Document for signing does not exist");
    }

    setTsaUrl(tsaUrl);

    // creating output document and prepare the IO streams.
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(signedFile);

    // load document
    doc = PDDocument.load(inputFile);

    int accessPermissions = SigUtils.getMDPPermission(doc);
    LogSystem.info("Document permission " + accessPermissions);
    if (accessPermissions == 1) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("No changes to the document are permitted due to DocMDP transform parameters dictionary");
    }
    // Note that PDFBox has a bug that visual signing on certified files with permission 2
    // doesn't work properly, see PDFBOX-3699. As long as this issue is open, you may want to
    // be careful with such files.

    PDSignature signature = null;
    PDAcroForm acroForm = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm(null);
    PDRectangle rect = null;

    // sign a PDF with an existing empty signature, as created by the CreateEmptySignatureForm example.
    String defaultSignatureField="Signature1";
    if (acroForm != null) {
        signature = findExistingSignature(acroForm, defaultSignatureField);
        if (signature != null) {
            rect = acroForm.getField(defaultSignatureField).getWidgets().get(0).getRectangle();
        }
    }

    if (signature == null) {
        // create signature dictionary
        signature = new PDSignature();
    }


    if (rect == null) {
        rect = createSignatureRectangle(doc, humanRect);
    }



    if (acroForm != null && acroForm.getNeedAppearances()) {
        // PDFBOX-3738 NeedAppearances true results in visible signature becoming invisible
        // with Adobe Reader
        if (acroForm.getFields().isEmpty()) {
            // we can safely delete it if there are no fields
            acroForm.getCOSObject().removeItem(COSName.NEED_APPEARANCES);
            // note that if you've set MDP permissions, the removal of this item
            // may result in Adobe Reader claiming that the document has been changed.
            // and/or that field content won't be displayed properly.
            // ==> decide what you prefer and adjust your code accordingly.
        } else {
            System.out.println("/NeedAppearances is set, signature may be ignored by Adobe Reader");
        }
    }

    boolean lockField = false;
    // register signature dictionary and sign interface
    signatureOptions = new SignatureOptions();

    signatureOptions.setVisualSignature(createVisualSignatureTemplate(doc, 0, rect, signature, isWithQR, name, userSignature.getDescOnly(), userSignature.getType(), userSignature.isVisible(), lockField));
    signatureOptions.setPage(page);
    signatureOptions.setPreferredSignatureSize(20000);

    // Optional: certify
    // can be done only if version is at least 1.5 and if not already set
    // doing this on a PDF/A-1b file fails validation by Adobe preflight (PDFBOX-3821)
    // PDF/A-1b requires PDF version 1.4 max, so don't increase the version on such files.
    if(userSignature.getType().equals("seal"))
    {

                PDSignatureField signatureField = doc.getSignatureFields().get(doc.getSignatureFields().size()-1);

                COSDictionary lockDict = new COSDictionary();
                lockDict.setItem(COSName.TYPE, COS_NAME_SIG_FIELD_LOCK);
                lockDict.setItem(COS_NAME_ACTION, COS_NAME_EXCLUDE);

                COSArray lockFields = new COSArray();
                lockFields.add(new COSString("textbox1"));

                lockDict.setItem(COSName.FIELDS, lockFields);

                signatureField.getCOSObject().setItem(COS_NAME_LOCK, lockDict);

                COSDictionary sigDict = signature.getCOSObject();
                COSDictionary transformParameters = new COSDictionary(lockDict);
                transformParameters.setItem(COSName.TYPE, COSName.TRANSFORM_PARAMS);
                transformParameters.setInt(COSName.P, 2);
                transformParameters.setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
                transformParameters.setDirect(true);

                COSDictionary referenceDict = new COSDictionary();
                referenceDict.setItem(COSName.TYPE, COSName.SIG_REF);
                referenceDict.setItem(COSName.TRANSFORM_METHOD, COSName.DOCMDP);
                referenceDict.setItem(COSName.DIGEST_METHOD, COSName.getPDFName("SHA256"));
                referenceDict.setItem(COSName.TRANSFORM_PARAMS, transformParameters);
                referenceDict.setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
                referenceDict.setDirect(true);

                COSArray referenceArray = new COSArray();
                referenceArray.add(referenceDict);
                sigDict.setItem(COSName.REFERENCE, referenceArray);
                sigDict.setItem(COS_NAME_LOCK, lockDict);
                referenceArray.setNeedToBeUpdated(true);

                COSDictionary catalogDict = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getCOSObject();
                COSDictionary permsDict = new COSDictionary();
                catalogDict.setItem(COSName.PERMS, permsDict);
                permsDict.setItem(COSName.DOCMDP, signature);
                catalogDict.setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
                permsDict.setNeedToBeUpdated(true);

                setValidation(false);

                final Predicate<PDField> shallBeLocked;
                final COSArray fields = lockDict.getCOSArray(COSName.FIELDS);
                final List<String> fieldNames = fields == null ? Collections.emptyList() :
                        fields.toList().stream().filter(c -> (c instanceof COSString)).map(s -> ((COSString)s).getString()).collect(Collectors.toList());
                final COSName action = lockDict.getCOSName(COSName.getPDFName("Action"));
                if (action.equals(COSName.getPDFName("Include"))) {
                    shallBeLocked = f -> fieldNames.contains(f.getFullyQualifiedName());
                } else if (action.equals(COSName.getPDFName("Exclude"))) {
                    shallBeLocked = f -> !fieldNames.contains(f.getFullyQualifiedName());
                } else if (action.equals(COSName.getPDFName("All"))) {
                    shallBeLocked = f -> true;
                } else { // unknown action, lock nothing
                    shallBeLocked = f -> false;
                }
                lockFields(doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm().getFields(), shallBeLocked);
            
        }
    }

    // default filter
    signature.setFilter(PDSignature.FILTER_ADOBE_PPKLITE);

    // subfilter for basic and PAdES Part 2 signatures
    signature.setSubFilter(PDSignature.SUBFILTER_ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);

    signature.setName("Name");
    signature.setLocation("location");
    if(userSignature.getType().equals("initials"))
    {
        this.setExternalSigning(true);
        signature.setReason("Agree");
    }
    if(userSignature.getType().equals("sign"))
    {
        this.setExternalSigning(true);
        signature.setReason(""");
    }
    if(userSignature.getType().equals("seal"))
    {
        this.setExternalSigning(true);
        signature.setReason(");
    }

    // the signing date, needed for valid signature
    signature.setSignDate(Calendar.getInstance());

    // do not set SignatureInterface instance, if external signing used
    SignatureInterface signatureInterface = isExternalSigning() ? null : this;

 
    doc.addSignature(signature, signatureInterface, signatureOptions);

    doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm().getField("Signature1").setPartialName(SignatureField);

    if (isExternalSigning()) {
        this.tsaUrl=tsaUrl;

        ExternalSigningSupport externalSigning = doc.saveIncrementalForExternalSigning(fos);

        // invoke external signature service
        byte[] cmsSignature =IOUtils.toByteArray(externalSigning.getContent());
        String sgn=null;
        try {
            sgn = signingProcess(cmsSignature);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            doc.close();
            return false;
        }

        // set signature bytes received from the service
        if (sgn != null)
        {
            externalSigning.setSignature(attachSignature(sgn));
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    } else {
        // write incremental (only for signing purpose)
        doc.saveIncremental(fos);
    }
    doc.close();


    // Do not close signatureOptions before saving, because some COSStream objects within
    // are transferred to the signed document.
    // Do not allow signatureOptions get out of scope before saving, because then the COSDocument
    // in signature options might by closed by gc, which would close COSStream objects prematurely.
    // See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3743
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(signatureOptions);
    return true;
}
```

in section

```
if(userSignature.getType().equals("seal"))
```

there i set lock dictionary and certify with **P** to 2

```
PDSignatureField signatureField = doc.getSignatureFields().get(doc.getSignatureFields().size()-1);

                COSDictionary lockDict = new COSDictionary();
                lockDict.setItem(COSName.TYPE, COS_NAME_SIG_FIELD_LOCK);
                lockDict.setItem(COS_NAME_ACTION, COS_NAME_EXCLUDE);

                COSArray lockFields = new COSArray();
                lockFields.add(new COSString("textbox1"));

                lockDict.setItem(COSName.FIELDS, lockFields);

                signatureField.getCOSObject().setItem(COS_NAME_LOCK, lockDict);

                COSDictionary sigDict = signature.getCOSObject();
                COSDictionary transformParameters = new COSDictionary(lockDict);
                transformParameters.setItem(COSName.TYPE, COSName.TRANSFORM_PARAMS);
                transformParameters.setInt(COSName.P, 2);
                transformParameters.setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
                transformParameters.setDirect(true);

                COSDictionary referenceDict = new COSDictionary();
                referenceDict.setItem(COSName.TYPE, COSName.SIG_REF);
                referenceDict.setItem(COSName.TRANSFORM_METHOD, COSName.DOCMDP);
                referenceDict.setItem(COSName.DIGEST_METHOD, COSName.getPDFName("SHA256"));
                referenceDict.setItem(COSName.TRANSFORM_PARAMS, transformParameters);
                referenceDict.setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
                referenceDict.setDirect(true);

                COSArray referenceArray = new COSArray();
                referenceArray.add(referenceDict);
                sigDict.setItem(COSName.REFERENCE, referenceArray);
                sigDict.setItem(COS_NAME_LOCK, lockDict);
                referenceArray.setNeedToBeUpdated(true);

                COSDictionary catalogDict = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getCOSObject();
                COSDictionary permsDict = new COSDictionary();
                catalogDict.setItem(COSName.PERMS, permsDict);
                permsDict.setItem(COSName.DOCMDP, signature);
                catalogDict.setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
                permsDict.setNeedToBeUpdated(true);

                setValidation(false);

                final Predicate<PDField> shallBeLocked;
                final COSArray fields = lockDict.getCOSArray(COSName.FIELDS);
                final List<String> fieldNames = fields == null ? Collections.emptyList() :
                        fields.toList().stream().filter(c -> (c instanceof COSString)).map(s -> ((COSString)s).getString()).collect(Collectors.toList());
                final COSName action = lockDict.getCOSName(COSName.getPDFName("Action"));
                if (action.equals(COSName.getPDFName("Include"))) {
                    shallBeLocked = f -> fieldNames.contains(f.getFullyQualifiedName());
                } else if (action.equals(COSName.getPDFName("Exclude"))) {
                    shallBeLocked = f -> !fieldNames.contains(f.getFullyQualifiedName());
                } else if (action.equals(COSName.getPDFName("All"))) {
                    shallBeLocked = f -> true;
                } else { // unknown action, lock nothing
                    shallBeLocked = f -> false;
                }
                lockFields(doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm().getFields(), shallBeLocked);
```

i assume the SignatureField add more data from function `createVisualSignatureTemplate()` then i get with `doc.getSignatureFields().get(doc.getSignatureFields().size()-1)`

but the new SignatureField not yet exist, what i miss ? the result certify signature successfull created but the lock not successful

[image: certify]

Comment: You mix two different concepts, that of a certification signature (**DocMDP** transform) and that of locking fields while signing (**FieldMDP** transform). By its letter the PDF specification appears to allow adding both transforms to the same signature field but I've neither seen that in a real life PDF yet nor is that the use case the specifications requires PDF writers to support in section 12.8.2.4 "FieldMDP" (ISO 32000-2). What you can do, of course, is set the signature field to *read-only* and its widget to *locked* in the course of adding the certification signature.

Comment: yes I tried to do that, but with what I've tried it doesn't work, refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54596361/pdf-signing-by-pdfbox-with-lock) to add lock dictionary but doesn't work

Comment: i mean there success with certify but not with lock the field

Comment: i try implement FieldMDP got message _Appearance generation for signature fields not yet implemented - you need to generate/update that manually_ but on example CreateVisibleSignature.java there are no example

Comment: *"i mean there success with certify but not with lock the field"* - Well, you should decide, do you want your signature to certify (**DocMDP** transform) or to lock (**FieldMDP** transform). I recommend applying only a single transform per signature.